# determining the equation of a line given slope and two intersecting lines?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, slope

*a line passes through the point of intersection of the lines $y = -\frac12x - 6 $ and $y = 2x + 4$. determine the equation of the line if it has a slope of $\frac12$.*

I'm completely lost, how should i answer this? I know that the line that has a slope of $\frac12$ is intersecting through $y = -\frac12x - 6$ and $y = 2x + 4$, which means that the points to these intersecting lines are the same to the line i'm trying to find the equation for, so how should i figure out those points? (unless my method  is wrong)

Answer (score 1):

OK, you are looking for a line, so you are looking for $k$ and $n$ in the equation $y=kx+n$. Basically, you want to calculate $k$ and $n$.

**Hint**:

1. What is the slope of the line $y=kx+n$?
2. What is the intersection of the lines $y=-\frac12 x - 6$ and $y=2x+4$?
3. If I know that the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the line $y=kx+n$, what equation do $x_0$ and $y_0$ satisfy?

Comment: 1) 1/2, 2) L1 (0, -6) L2 (0,4), so do i use one of these points to satisfy the equation and solve for n?

Comment: @ineedgr10mathhelp wrong and wrong. For 1) I am asking in **general**, if I give you an equation $y=kx+n$, what is the slope of this line? Like, what is the slope of the line $y=2x+5$? And what is the slope of $y=x+1$? For 2) no. Those are the intersections of the two lines with the $y$ axis, but not the intersection of the two lines among themselves. You want to find a point that is on **both** lines!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hints @5xum gave you, you should see a connection between y=kx+n and y=mx+b (which is what most teachers use).

1. The slope of y=kx+n is k. The question gives that to you.
2. You *can* find the intersection of the two lines algebraically. 
   Since y=y, then -1/2 x - 6 = 2x + 4. Now solve for x. I personally prefer to graph the lines on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lu2zokdt30).
3. When you find the point, plug in what you know to y=kx+n. So far, you know k (slope) and x&y (the point of intersection). *Remember to multiply k times x.* You are left with n as the unknown so solve for n. (Get the n by itself on one side of the equation and a number on the other side.)
4. For your final equation, set up y=kx+n and fill in the k (slope) and n (y-intercept of the new line).

Comment: Most teachers where I'm from use $y=kx+n$, not $y=mx + b$...

Comment: I suppose it could be a regional difference. I have occasionally seen y=ax+b

Answer (score 0):

The intersection point of the lines $y = -\frac12x-6$ and $y = 2x+4$ is a point where the value of $y$ for both the lines is same. So,
$$
-\frac12x-6 = 2x+4
$$
$$-\frac52x = 10
$$
$$x = -4
$$
So the point of intersection is at $x=-4$ and $y = -\frac12x-6 = -\frac12(-4) - 6 = -4$. The point of intersection is $(-4, -4)$. Now we know that the unknown line with slope $\frac12$ passes through the point $(-4, -4)$.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Any line passing through the intersection of the given lines is

$$ \lambda( -x/2-6) +(1-\lambda)(2 x +4) = x/2 + C $$

Put $x=0$ in the above equation,it gives

$-10 \lambda +4 = C  \tag1$

Collecting $x$ term coefficients and equating

$$ -\lambda/2 + 2 - 2\lambda = \frac12 ,\, \lambda =\frac35 \tag2 $$

Eliminate $\lambda$ from (1), (2)

$$C= -2,  \tag3$$

So required straight line has equation

$$ y = x/2 -2.$$